# how to get a projection of aggregates over a set

Tags: linq-to-entities

T-SQL queries such as:

```
select sum(amount), min(amount), max(amount) from sales where salesdate < getDate()
```

seem difficult to translate into Linq to Entites.

On first guess i would try

```
var result = from s in entites.Sales where s.SalesDate < DateTime.Today
group s by 1 into g
select new { 
AmountSum = g.Sum(x=> x.amount), 
AmountMin= g.Min(x=>x.amount),
AmountMax= g.Max(x=>x.amount)}
```

Is this in fact the best way to accomplish the same thing the t-sql is doing?  Obviously the SQL that EF generates includes a group by which gives my a moment of concern.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `group s by 1 into g` statement? I would think you could do that with no problem and then it shouldnt generate a group by statement.

Comment: If I remove the group s by 1 into g then what do I hang the Sum off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing around your query - using a sample dictionary to illustrate:

```
Dictionary<int, int> sampleDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

sampleDictionary.Add(4, 5);
sampleDictionary.Add(7, 8);
sampleDictionary.Add(1, 2);

var val = new
{
    Max = sampleDictionary.Max(x => x.Key),
    Min = sampleDictionary.Min(x => x.Key),
     Sum = sampleDictionary.Sum(x => x.Key)
};

Console.WriteLine(val);
Console.ReadKey();
```

This selects the max, min, and sum of the keys into a new anonymous object. You could write that like:

```
var set = entites.Sales.Where(x => x.SalesDate < DateTime.Today);

var val = new
{
    Max = set.Max(x => x.Key),
    Min = set.Min(x => x.Key),
    Sum = set.Sum(x => x.Key)
};
```